# Is the exponential map a symplectomorphism?

Tags: symplectic-geometry

In the case of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ the exponential map just becomes 
$$ exp_{p}(v) = p + v$$
which results in 
$$ Dexp_{p}(w)_{v} = w $$ and proves that this map is a symplectomorphism.

I am wondering if this is also the case in a general symplectic manifold and in the likely event that it isn't true what possible properties are necessary to prove it is a symplectomorphism.

Comment: see Lectures on Symplectic Geometry-Ana Cannas da Silva 4.2

Comment: @BeyAlexander The mentioned reference gives a property for a general symplectomorphism, I am wondering if their is one more specificly for exponential maps?